# Why does OnResume reset the values in my SharedPreference object?

Tags: android, kotlin

When the user clicks on a button, it switches a boolean value in a sharedpreference object to true/false. When I access that state later on in the activity, the state is saved and works fine. However when I click on the Android's back button to pause the app, and resume the app again, the SharedPreference object is switched to true. Even though it was at false when I examined the onPause() method with a debugger.

Basically I've tried examining the state of the SharedPreference object in the onPause, onCreate, and onResume methods of my activity. I'm not sure why the value gets switched back to its default value (true) during the onCreate method.

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    val p = pauseButtonTracker.pauseButtonStateAtResume() // value is false 


}



override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val q = pauseButtonTracker.pauseButtonStateAtResume() // value is switched to true 

//...
```

// object that manages the shared preferences object I was talking about

```
class PauseButtonTracker(context: Context) { 
    private val PAUSE_BUTTON_TRACKER = "PAUSE_BUTTON_TRACKER"
    private val WAS_AT_RESUME = "WAS_AT_RESUME"
    private val pauseTracker = context.getSharedPreferences(PAUSE_BUTTON_TRACKER, 0)
    private val pauseTrackerEditor = pauseTracker.edit() 

    fun pauseButtonStateAtResume(): Boolean{
        return pauseTracker.getBoolean(WAS_AT_RESUME, true)
    }

    fun switchPauseButtonStateToPause(){ 
        pauseTrackerEditor.putBoolean(WAS_AT_RESUME, false)
        pauseTrackerEditor.apply() 
    }

    fun switchPauseButtonStateToResume(){
        pauseTrackerEditor.putBoolean(WAS_AT_RESUME, true)
        pauseTrackerEditor.apply()
    }


}
```

value contained in,

```
pauseButtonTracker.pauseButtonStateAtResume()
```

should've remained false, when onResume is called, yet it gets switched to true for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

On first activity where `onPause()` is called ,

you should have called `switchPauseButtonStateToPause`

before `val p = pauseButtonTracker.pauseButtonStateAtResume()`

and then call  `onResume()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Woops, the solution was to just put a debugger on

```
fun switchPauseButtonStateToResume(){
    pauseTrackerEditor.putBoolean(WAS_AT_RESUME, true)
    pauseTrackerEditor.apply()
}
```

To see if it was getting called for whatever reason.

It turns out that it was being called from the main activity, right before it switches to the activity with the pause/resume button. Therefore if the user clicks pause, and exits out of the app, and resumes it again, it will always switch back to the resume state.